# UIDatePickerStyle.compact does not work on 13.7

Tags: uikit, uidatepicker

The Apple documentation says that .compact style of a UIDatePicker is available from iOS 13.4.

When I launch in the simulator in iOS 13.7 my app with deployment target to iOS 13.4 and use a UIDatePicker it is displayed a the classic wheel. That does not sound normal according to documentation! Any idea?

Comment: Yeah, I confirm it's not working. I have exactly the same environment as you. Zero info on the web ‍♂️

Comment: I seem to be experiencing the same. iOS deployment target of 13.4, running on a 13.7 simulator. With the `.compact` preferred style set, the date picker continues to display the `.wheels` style components. Anyone figure a work-around to get the compact style?

Comment: Well, by the way, it look like the wheel is coming back in iOS 15. No sure that `.compact` was a good idea.